# How to troubleshoot Flot Touch

Tags: jquery, flot

Where should I begin troubleshooting the jQuery Flot Touch plugin?

My current problem is that it is completely unresponsive- it not only doesn't respond to touch devices, it breaks the currently working Navigation plugin (which works very well on desktop devices). It also causes the graph to expand beyond the range of the placeholder element.

We aren't using exotic options and stepping through the plugin didn't reveal anything particularly obvious. Are there any common pitfalls to check for in our implementation? Thank you.